# How to use FontAwsome as a font-family in Angular

Tags: css, angular, font-awesome, font-family

I want to use the fontAwsome as a fontFamily in my css file, in order to change the `<li>` after icon.

In normal HTML/CSS i can do like this with no issue :

```
ul li:not(:last-child):after {
font-family: 'FontAwesome';
content: '\f105';
font-size: 13px;
top: 0px;
right: 0;
position: absolute;
}
```

but with angular I can't access the FontAwesome in my css files.

In my component html, I use this with no issues : `<fa-icon icon="home"></fa-icon>` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `npm i font-awesome`
2. import in your css : `@import "~font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"`
3. in your html, you just need to do something like this : `<i class="fa fa-home"></i>`

Comment: I want to use it in my css file, as a font-family, like this `font-family: 'FontAwesome';`

Comment: You do the same thing, just forget the last step :)

Comment: It works for me, thx;
But i have a qst, I am using this too in my project : 
`"@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "latest",` ; Can I just use this one in my css instead of installing the new `font-awesome`?